# Ternary operator is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, servlets, jstl

In my code, I am setting a variable called `language` via `JSTL`. This is how I do this.

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri= "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set var="language" value="${not empty param.language ? param.language : not empty language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}" scope="session" />
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="text" />
```

I have a JQuery code, which will check the `language` and display the content accordingly.

```
<script >
    $(function() {
        $('#SelecttheCategory').on('change', function() {
            alert("${language}");
            val = $(this).val();

            $.get("DynamicPopProductList?categoryID=" + val, function(responseJson) {

                var $dropdown = $("#Selecttheproducts");
                $dropdown.empty();

                $.each(responseJson, function(index, item) {
                    $dropdown.append($("<option />").val(item.idproduct).text($ {
                        language
                    } == 'si' ? item.sinhalaName : item.productName));
                });

            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

If the language is `sinhala` I need to display `item.sinhalaName` and if it is not, I am displaying `item.productName`. Anyway, this do not work as expected. I do not get anything. However in my `alert`, it shows the `language` correctly as `si`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If the `alert()` works as expected then you will have a reference error in the console.

Comment: Just FYI the ternary operator is a Javascript construct, it has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: `${language} == 'si'` is e.g. expanded to `si == 'si'`, and since there is no variable named `si`, it means `undefined == 'si'`, which of course is **`false`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `${language}` value is output to the source on the server side then you need to wrap it in quotes for the Javascript syntax to work correctly. Try this:

```
var optionText = '${language}' === 'si' ? item.sinhalaName : item.productName;
$dropdown.append($("<option />", {
  value: item.idproduct,
  text: optionText
});
```